# Associativity of the same operator precedence -- *start++

Tags: c, operator-precedence

Why does the following expression:

```
total += *start++;
```

Evaluate to:

```
total += (*start)++;
```

And not:

```
total += *(start++); // though this doesn't really matter either it would be the same
```

The `++` (postfix increment) and `*` (dereference have the same precedence and associate from right-to-left, so why isn't the `++` postfix evaluated first?

---

Or, does the postfix evaluate after a sequence point, and so:

```
total += *++start
```

Would evaluate to:

```
total += *(++start)
```

But because the postfix happens after:

```
total += *start++
```

Would evaluate to:

```
total += (*start)++;
```

In other words, Right-to-Left associativity is not important in the above expression, because even post-fix is evaluated after not during the expression evaluation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The postfix `++` operator *does* have higher precedence than the dereference operator `*`.  So the expression parses as:

```
total += *(start++);
```

What might be confusing you is that the result of the postfix `++` operator is the operand *before* it is incremented.  The actual increment happens as an unsequenced side effect of the expression.

So this expression takes the original value of `start`, dereferences it, and adds that value to `total`.  By the time the expression is fully evaluated, `start` is incremented.

Note that this differs from:

```
total += (*start)++;
```

Because this increments what `start` points to instead of `start` itself.

Comment: It might be mentionable that the precedence and associativity are independent of the [order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order).