# Why *c++ increasing pointer value but not the ascii of first Char?

Tags: c, char-pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *c = "test";

    while (*c != '\0') {
        printf("%c", *c);
        *c++; // or c++ both produced same result. ie test
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As *c++ should increase value and c++ should increase pointer address. But both are increasing pointer why?

Comment: Because of [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: _`*c++` should increase value_: Really? Why?

Comment: Can you please explain ?

Comment: Because *c printing value and in while it acting  as value too.

Comment: Sorry, but don't understand what to explain. Post-increment `++` operator has a higher precedence, so it is evaluated first.

Comment: A [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66073386/associativity-of-the-same-operator-precedence-start) was asked & answered an hour ago.

Comment: `char *c = "test";` => `const char *c = "test";`

Comment: Note also, you *can't* accomplish what you want in this case, since the string would be a constant and can't be modified. An "array" declaration like `char c[] = "test";` would permit modification.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to operator precedence ++ has higher precedence than *

Answer (score 1):

> But both are increasing pointer why?

That's because of something called operator precedence. Take a look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

If you want to increase the value then you should be doing

```
(*c)++ //increment the value at address c
```

And as a bit of advice your code is more 'C' than 'C++'. Avoid raw pointers where possible and use the iostream library instead of `'printf'`

Comment: It would be good to mention that the dereference after `c++` results are never used. Use `-Wunused-value` to see the specific warning.

Comment: @pcodex. Your link is helpful. Thank you